# For any prime numbers $p$, any integers $a$, any natural numbers $k$, if $p|a^k$ then $p|a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

Does this make sense?

Proof (induction on $k$)

Base case:

Let $k=1$, then trivially $p|a$

Induction hypothesis:

Let $p\mid a^k \implies p \mid a$ hold for any arbitrary $k$ in the natural numbers

Induction step:

$p\mid a^{k+1} \implies p\mid a^k a^1 \implies p\mid a^k$, which holds true via the inductive hypothesis. Thus $p \mid a$

Comment: How does your induction step work when k=1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part $p\mid a^k a^1 \implies p\mid a^k$ might need a bit of more reasoning.

Assume that $p \not\mid a$, then as $p$ is prime you have $\gcd(p,a) = 1$. Here the fact that $p$ is prime comes useful. Then by Euclid's Lemma as $\gcd(p,a) = 1$ we have $p\mid a^k a^1 \implies p\mid a^k$

Comment: Thank you @stefan4024 !